# Butterknife not working AT ALL in my Android application

Tags: java, android, view, butterknife

This is a very odd behaviour and I cannot understand why, basically [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) is **NOT binding** any views at all. Please see below code:

This is a **Fragment**:

```
@BindView(R.id.share_detail_swipe)
public SMSwipeRefreshLayout view1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_share_details, container, false);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view1.setRefreshing(true); // NPE here
}
```

A very simple code! But if I start the application, it will fail with `NullPointerException` complaining `view1` is **NULL**. This is very frustrating as I am doing exactly what the [API Doc](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) tells me to do.

Anyone have clues on what's going on here? Below is the `view_share_details.xml`:

```
<com.*.presentation.view.smwidget.SMSwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/share_detail_swipe"
tools:context="com.*.fragment.ShareDetailsFragment"
>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/detail_share_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/detail_share_name_tv"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/detail_share_username_tv"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/detail_share_date_tv"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/detail_share_description_tv"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</com.*.presentation.view.smwidget.SMSwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And the logcat output:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.joelmin.sharemon, PID: 4981
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.*.presentation.view.smwidget.SMSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at com.joelmin.sharemon.presentation.fragment.ShareDetailsFragment.showRefreshing(ShareDetailsFragment.java:83)
    at com.joelmin.sharemon.presentation.presenter.ShareDetailsPresenter.fetchShare(ShareDetailsPresenter.java:25)
    at com.joelmin.sharemon.presentation.fragment.ShareDetailsFragment.onViewCreated(ShareDetailsFragment.java:102)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6843)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Could you provide the your view_share_details layout xml and also your app's build.gradle file?

Comment: post your xml file code here

Comment: Just did, please check it out

Comment: did you enable `JACK`? Because annotation procsesing doesn't work with JACK. Also, enable annotation processing in your IDE.

Comment: Where is view with id `view1`? i think you should use `share_detail_swipe` instead of `view1`

Comment: change it to `@BindView(R.id.share_detail_swipe)
public SMSwipeRefreshLayout view1;`

Comment: I am sorry everyone, it is `R.id.share_detail_swipe`, I just typed the wrong one in the question :(

Comment: @EpicPandaForce That is a very good point, I do not have Jack but I do have Retrolambda, would this have an effect on my annotation?

Comment: @ankitaggarwal how do you include the Butterknife's library in your app's build.gradle file? 

You have to call:
***apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'***

and also your dependency should be:
***apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'***

Comment: @Seishin I simply use a `compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1', isn't that enough?
`

Comment: Nope. 
Change your dependency to:
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1' -> apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'

And put
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt' 
below the
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Comment: I was surprised by myself - but Seishin is right, check the [github page](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) under the header `Download`.

Comment: Omg thanks @Seishin that did it!! Why does it have to work differently from other libraries...thanks!

Comment: @JoelMin because it consists of a library and an annotation processor, and to make annotation processing work, you have to apply the android-apt gradle plugin. Also the processor was separated from the library itself for cleanliness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the Butterknife library as follows:

You have to add in your dependencies:
***apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'***

And also to put bellow the apply plugin: 'com.android.application':
***apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'***

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

Comment: You're welcome! I've spent a whole day wondering what is wrong... just like you. :)

Just read the docs more carefully when a new version of a lib is released.

Comment: I had the same problem in March of 2017. The setup requirements changed again and I was trying to use ButterKnife from various online guides. After reading this answer and comments, I went to the Butter Knife web site and changed my app to match the current instructions. I needed to remove the `apply plugin:` line, also the `dependencies {classpath...}` line. Finally, I changed to the current 8.5.1 version and all worked correctly. As Seishin said, I just needed to read the docs for the current version and setup accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor` in your app's build.grade file

use:

```
kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
```

instead of:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
```

Read here for more info:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#download